# CreateModelMixin TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying to insert a new row into a 2 column table where one column references the authenticated user (model references user model via a FK) and the other being a variable passed through the url.

urls.py

```
url('^(?P<update>-?\d+.?\d+)/$', views.UpdateViewSet)
```

views.py

```
class UpdateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)  
    serializer_class = serializers.UpdateSerializer
    def create(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        update = self.kwargs['update']
        return self.create(user=self.request.user,update=update)
```

Traceback

```
 File "\Backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "\Backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "\Backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

```
class Update(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5,max_digits=6)
```

Comment: can you add complete error traceback?

Comment: Edited with traceback

Comment: It may help you https://learnbatta.com/blog/viewsets-in-django-rest-framework-83/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [***class-based views***--[Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/#class-based-views), you should've call [**`as_view()`**--[Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

```
url('^(?P<update>-?\d+.?\d+)/$', views.UpdateViewSet.as_view({"post":"create"}))
```

---

#### Update-1

Change your view as below,

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UpdateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UpdateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        update_instance = Update.objects.create(user=request.user, update=self.kwargs['update'])
        return Response(self.get_serializer(update_instance).data)
```

Comment: TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: I fixed that as well, now I'm seeing TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: What are you trying to do with `self.create(user=self.request.user,update=update)` line of code? Can you clarify that?

Comment: The Update model has two fields, one is a FK to the User model and the other is the update value. I'm trying to insert the record with authenticated user and the update value.

Comment: can you add that model?

Comment: Updated. It's just a normal 2 field model.

Comment: check my **`Update-1`** section. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are configuring the url wrongly, do like this:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'update', views.UpdateViewSet, basename='update')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Or

```
 url(r'^(?P<update>-?\d+.?\d+)/$', views.UpdateViewSet.as_view(actions={'post': 'create'}))
```